# Can I change the __call__ of a Python Object without rewriting the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Consider the following scenario in pseudo-python-code:

```py
    class Component_i: # same for i = 1,2,3,...
        __call__(self, input):
            return input
   
    class MyClass:
        def __init__(self):
            self.comp_1 = Component_1()
            self.comp_2 = Component_2()
            self.comp_3 = Component_3()
        def __call__(self, input):
            return self.comp_3(self.comp_2(self.comp_1(input)))
    
    A = MyClass()
```

Now i would like to do the following:

```py
    class Component_2B:
        __call__(self, input, option = True):
            if option:
                return input
            else:
                return do_stuff_with_input(input)
            
    A.comp_2 = Component_2B()
```

And then I would like to change the `__call__` of A to also accept the optional input `option`, and this optional input to be passed to `A.comp_2` whenever it is called. But to make things complicated, I would like to achieve this **without** rewriting the `__call__`.

Does anyone have an Idea?

---

Here is a MWE:

```py
    class MultiplyWithParameter:
        def __init__(self, parameter: float):
            self.p = parameter
        def __call__(self, input: float):
            return self.p * input

    class ProcessDataClass:
        def __init__(self, parameter: float):
            self.mul = MultiplyWithParameter(parameter)
        def __call__(self, input: float):
            input = input * 5 + 4
            input = self.mul(input)
            return input - 3

    DataProcessor = ProcessDataClass(2.5)

    class OptionalMultiplyWithParameter:
        def __init__(self, parameter: float):
            self.p = parameter
        def __call__(self, input: float, multiply: Bool = True):
            if multiply:
                return self.p * input
            else:
                return input
```

now i want to set

```py
    DataProcessor.mul = OptionalMultiplyWithParameter(DataProcessor.mul.p)
```

and use `DataProcessor(4.23, False)`. This shall pass the `False` to `DataProcessor.mul` during the call. I want to do this **without** rewriting the `__call__` of `ProcessDataClass` (otherwise would be simple).

---

Here is some Motivation:

Assume there is a package called `coollibrary` in the internet from which I would like to use function `coolclassfactory`. This function returns an Instance of `CoolClass` which has a range of attributes and a `__call__`. Some of its attributes might be of class `ProcessWithParameters`. When initialized, `CoolClass` loads parameters from the Internet. Now I would like to give my `CoolClass` Instance which i built with `coolclassfactory` as an attribute to `MyClass`. But I would then like to replace all attributes that my `CoolClass` Instance has and that are of class `ProcessWithParameters` with another class `OptionalProcessWithParameters`, which essentially allows at runtime to choose between two possible ways of how to process input with parameters. Since this runtime option is new, i have to add it during the call (i assume? - here is important this should be safe to be used in multiprocessing!). Now unfortunately because I use `coolclassfactory` and this returns one of many possible subclasses of `CoolClass` each with an individual `__call__`, i can not simply rewrite the `__call__`, because that changes depending on how `coolclassfactory` is called. Essentially I would have to rewrite all the calls of subclasses of `CoolClass`, which I am trying to avoid...

Comment: If you starting writing classes with a name sequence, you are probably having a large design issue.

Comment: @KlausD. this is pseudocode....

Comment: Pseudo-code leads to pseudo-understanding of your problem which leads to a pseudo-answer. Try to give a minimal working example in real code.

Comment: @KlausD. Ok. I have added a MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always subclass what ever class and rewrite/expand/adjust any part of the original to your liking and with the use of [super()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) access the original functionality

from your example, something like this for example:

```
class ProcessDataClassOptional(ProcessDataClass):
    def __init__(self, parameter: float):
        super().__init__(parameter) #use the original init to do its thing
        self._mul = OptionalMultiplyWithParameter(parameter) #our modification

    def __call__(self, input: float, multiply: Bool = True):
        self.mul = lambda x: self._mul(x, multiply) # now the original will use our modify mul
        return super().__call__(input)
```

and now you can instead use the adjusted version

```
DataProcessor = ProcessDataClassOptional(2.5)
DataProcessor(4.23)
DataProcessor(4.23, False)
```

when used as the original there shouldn't be any change, but now you can use the new behavior with it too